# WPF Bind in Button's ControlTemplate to property of CommandParameter?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, data-binding

I am trying to create a generic page navigation button using a Style and ControlTemplate. The idea is that the destination page is the CommandParameter of the button:

```
 <Button Height="64" Width="64" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonViewTileStyle}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=ChangePage}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=HomePage}"/>
```

...and every page has a DisplayName and IconName property that I would like to use to use in the ControlTemplate. Here is a non-working example with just the display name:

```
  <Style x:Key="ButtonViewTileStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            Text="{Binding CommandParameter.DisplayName,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Any suggestions on what the Text= binding should be to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code.

```
<Window.Resources>       
    <Style x:Key="ButtonViewTileStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        Text="{Binding CommandParameter.DisplayName,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>   
<StackPanel>        
    <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Width="100" Height="25" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonViewTileStyle}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PageDetails}"></Button>       
</StackPanel>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }      
}
 class TestViewModel
{
    private CommndPrm pageDetials;

    public CommndPrm PageDetails
    {
        get { return pageDetials; }
        set { pageDetials = value; }
    }


    public TestViewModel()
    {            
        pageDetials = new CommndPrm() { DisplayName="Test"};            
    }      

}

class CommndPrm
{
    private string displayName;

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return displayName; }
        set { displayName = value; }
    }

}
```